# How to parse a conditional statement in Lark parser python?

Tags: python, parsing

So I'm parsing a programming language in python, using the Lark parser, so how would I achieve that? I have the following lark grammar:

```py
?bool: TRUE              -> true
     | FALSE             -> false

?condition: expr "==" bool -> bool_comparison
          | expr "==" expr -> expr_comparison

?statement: "print" "(" expr ")" ";" -> print_statement
          | "input" "(" expr ")" ";" -> input_statement

?if : "if" condition "{" statement "}" -> if_statement
```

The above is from my `.lark` file, and heres my transformer code.

```py
def if_statement(self, condition, eval_expr):
    if condition:
       eval_expr
```

I know that doesn't do anything, but I can't figure out a way to evaluate and compare the if statement, I get none if I parse something like this:

```
if 5 == 5 { print("HI"); }
>>> None
```

Help would be appreicated, thanks! My full code is on github: https://github.com/AbooMinister25/ToyLang

Comment: Your transformer methods must each have a single parameter like `s`, so `def if_statement(self,s):` and then elements of s correspond to the parsed stuff for an if_statement. I started by each transformer function printing out the name of the function and the values in s, and worked it out from there. The transformer function has to return the thing you want from an if_statement, i.e. true/false I guess.

Comment: You’re getting None because your `if_statement()` doesn’t have an explicit return of a value, so it returns None. None may not be wrong - what do you _want_ as the result of an if statement?

Comment: I want it to evaluate an expression if a given condition is true.

Comment: Yes, but for the if statement as a whole what do you want the result to be - does `if condition { statement }` return a value to be used by something  else? Similarly the print and input statements, do you want them to have a result? Probably not?

Comment: In your if_statment() add `return 23` at the end and the result of your if_statement will suddenly be 23 instead of None

Comment: Oh wait guys I figured it out, I did `return eval_expr`, and it works.

Comment: NOTE You don’t want to evaluate `eval_expr` if the condition is false. That’s why it’s not so obvious what `if_statement()` should return: None may be valid, i.e. the correct thing to return